# Override WooCommerce product gallery

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Default behaviour of WooCommerce Product gallery: 
    1. All the gallery images appear below a single image
    2. Clicking on any image on the below slides the current image to the clicked image

What's expected:
    1. Hide the below thumbnail images
    2. Slider should auto slide
    3. There should be arrows to control the slider

Comment: You can try any plugin for this

Comment: Can you name some or one of them?

Comment: Try this Product Gallery Slider for Woocommerce https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-product-gallery-slider/